# Google Spreadsheet conditional counting function

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I am having trouble writing a function for this need (in Google spreadsheets):

I have 2 columns A and B.

I want to be able to get a percentage based on those two columns. I want to count the number of times a specific value is found in A and only if B has a certain value in it.

Example:

```
  A       B
name1    yes
name2    no
name7    no
name1    yes
name1    no
name2    yes
```

I would like to function to only give me the percentage of times name1 is found when it is associated with a yes in column B.

If you need any more information and clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Answered I received in the Google Support Forum:

```
=counta(iferror(filter(B:B,A:A="name1",B:B="yes")))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the A value (eg "name1") held in say C1 and the B value (eg "yes") in say D1 then:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,C1,B:B,D1)
```

is shorter and more versatile.